# optimizing query order by results to Using filesort;

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, filesort

Query :

```
    SELECT
        r.reply_id,
        r.msg_id,
        r.uid,
        r.body,
        r.date,
        u.username as username,
        u.profile_picture as profile_picture
    FROM
        pm_replies as r
        LEFT JOIN users as u
            ON u.uid = r.uid
    WHERE
        r.msg_id = '784351921943772258'

    ORDER BY r.date DESC
```

i tried all index combinations i could think of, searched in google how best i could index this but nothing worked.

this query takes **0,33** on **500** returned items and **counting**...

---

**EXPLAIN:**

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  r   ALL     index1  NULL    NULL    NULL    540     Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  u   eq_ref  uid     uid     8   site.r.uid  1
```

**SHOW CREATE pm_replies**

```
CREATE TABLE `pm_replies` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `reply_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `msg_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `body` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `index1` (`msg_id`,`date`,`uid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=541 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**SHOW CREATE users**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `password` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `profile_picture` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `date_registered` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2004 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE pm_replies`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`, `EXPLAIN SELECT <your entire select here>`? Other than that, probable index will be `r.msg_id, r.uid` and you'll want `u.uid` to have an index too (best unique).

Comment: do you have indexed u.uid, r.uid, r.msg_id and r.date? EDIT: I see... Try to index date in pm_replies

Comment: @Uriel_SVK thats correct

Comment: @fx-user - You need composite/covering indexes. One index that covers multiple fields. With `KEY IndexN (msg_id, date)` you get all records sorted by date *for the same msg_id*. So when you pick one msg_id, they're all pre-sorted by date for you.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

For the query as it is, the best indexes would seem to be...

```
pm_replies: (msg_id, date, uid)
users:      (uid)
```

The important one is `pm_replies`.  You use it to both filter your data (the filter column is first) then order your data (the order column is second).

The would be different if you removed the filter.  Then you'd just want `(date, uid)` as your index.

The last field in the index just makes it a fraction friendlier to the join, the important part is actually the index on `users`.

There is a lot more that coudl be said on this, a whole chapter in a book at the very least, and several books if your wanted to.  But I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Not that my suggested index for `pm_replies` is one index covering three fields, and not just three indexes.  This ensures that all the entries in the index are pre-sorted by those columns.  It's like sorting data in Excel by three columns.

Having three separate indexes is like having the Excel data on three tabs.  Each sorted by a different fields.

Only whith one index over three fields do you get this behaviour...
- You can select one 'bunch' of records with the same msg_id
- That whole 'bunch' are next to each other, no gaps, etc
- That whole 'bunch' are sorted in date order for that msg_id
- For any rows with the same date, they're ordered by user_id

(Again the user_id part is really very minor.)

Comment: so you are saying to create 1 index with 3 columns?if so this still doesnt seem to help.

Comment: @fxuser - Unless it's a MyISAM strangeness, I'm not sure.  How many records actually exist in your table?  Also, could you try creating the index separately?  `CREATE INDEX ix_pm_replies_2 ON pm_replies (msg_id, date, user_id)`

Comment: @dems there are about 540 records in the table and i pull them all without LIMITing the query. A solution could be to add limit even if i would not want to do that. i added your index which is the same with mine but doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: @fxuser - When you say "pull them all" do you mean that you're removing the WHERE clause and getting all msg_id's?

Comment: No, the query is as you see above, but for now all these are dummy data and generated by me only. So i am pulling 540 records that belong to my user and it seems to take too long... but adding limit will solve the problem but require other actions to load the older records

Comment: @fxuser - So ***all*** the dummy data records have the same `msg_id`?

Comment: @dems yes. msg_id is the message and reply_id is a reply that belongs to msg_id... simply i get all replies that belong to the message and are posted by me.

Comment: @fxuser - I'm stumped.  Works on SQL Server, MySQL-InnoDB and SyBase.

Comment: changed to InnoDB from MyISAM but still the same load time, using where;using filesort; - im going to pass on this... will add LIMITs and see how its going...

Comment: MySQL's optimizer might decide **using the index is not worth is**, seeing the table only has  500 rows. Does your `EXPLAIN SELECT` now shows it's using this index? What happens when you use `FORCE INDEX`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT
        r.reply_id,
        r.msg_id,
        r.uid,
        r.body,
        r.date,
        u.username as username,
        u.profile_picture as profile_picture
    FROM
        pm_replies as r
        LEFT JOIN users as u
            ON (u.uid = r.uid AND r.msg_id = '784351921943772258')
    ORDER BY r.date DESC
```

in my case it help.

Comment: That is functionally different, and most likely incorrect. The OP takes a specific set of rows from `pm_replies`, based on `msg_id`, and then left joins them to `users`. *(Possibly just one row.)* You take ***all*** rows from `pm_replies` but only join them to `users` for a specific `msg_id`, all the others still come through, but as NULLs. This is not an answer.

Comment: did you index fields r.msg_id and r.date?

Comment: @Miro yeah both columns are indexed

Answer (score 0):

Add date to your index1 key so that msg_id and date are both in the index.

Answer (score 0):

What [Dems is saying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9735000/533120) should be correct, but there is one additional detail if you are using InnoDB: perhaps you are paying the price of [secondary indexes on clustered tables](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/) - essentially, accessing a row through the secondary index requires **additional** lookup trough the primary, i.e. clustering index. This "double lookup" might make the index less attractive to the query optimizer.

To alleviate this, try [covering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index) the **all** the fields in your select statement with the index:

```
pm_replies: (msg_id, date, uid, reply_id, body, date)
users:      (uid, username, profile_picture)
```

Comment: all my tables are myisam, i changed to innodb just to test dems comment.

Comment: @fxuser One more thing: have you tried using index `pm_replies: (msg_id, uid)`, since this is a LEFT join and `users` is the "outer" table. Also, did you try removing LEFT, just to see what happens?

Comment: @fxuser Or even `pm_replies: (uid, msg_id)`?

Comment: tried adding a 2 column index and either ways didnt help either... still using filesort and loading times are the same... even when i removed left join.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the optimizer is trying to force the index by ID to make the join to the user table.  Since you are doing a left-join (which doesn't make sense since I would expect every entry to have a user ID, thus a normal INNER JOIN), I'll keep it left join.

So, I would try the following.  Query just the replies based on the MESSAGE ID and order by the date descending on its own merits, THEN left join, such as

```
SELECT
        r.reply_id,
        r.msg_id,
        r.uid,
        r.body,
        r.date,
        u.username as username,
        u.profile_picture as profile_picture
    FROM
        ( select R2.* 
             from pm_replies R2
             where r2.msg_id = '784351921943772258' ) r
        LEFT JOIN users as u
            ON u.uid = r.uid
    ORDER BY
        r.date DESC
```

In addition, since I don't have MySQL readily available, and can't remember if order by is allowed in a sub-query, if so, you can optimize the inner prequery (using alias "R2") and put the order by there, so it uses the (msgid, date) index and returns just that set... THEN joins to user table on the ID which no index is required at that point from the SOURCE result set, just the index on the user table to find the match.

Comment: this takes even longer to load and adding 1 index on 2 columns(msg_id, date) wont work either.

Comment: @fxuser, sorry it didn't work, but you always have to try alternatives from what the engine may be thinking.  It was a simple test and either worked faster or not.  Just one of many approaches to look for performance improvements.